# Gradle Android Error: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact

Tags: java, android, spring, gradle

I'm trying to consume a SOAP service in my Android app. I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/). When I try to run my app I get an error:

```
Error: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
```

I'm on Android N (SDK 25 - I can't bump to 26 like the error message indicates) and it's a brand new project just created by Android Studio.

Here's my project build.gradle file which I haven't changed:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here's my app build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

configurations {
    jaxb
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// tag::wsdl[]
task genJaxb {
    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generatedjava/jaxb"
    ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
    ext.schema = "https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/wsdl.aspx?ver=2017-10-01"

    outputs.dir classesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
            mkdir(dir: classesDir)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema,
                    package: "hello.wsdl") {
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }

            javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.8, target: 1.8, debug: true,
                    debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                src(path: sourcesDir)
                include(name: "**/*.java")
                include(name: "*.java")
            }

            copy(todir: classesDir) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// end::wsdl[]

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.magicmirror"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.tooling'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json'
        exclude 'META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.factories'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.schemas'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter"
    implementation "org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core"
    implementation(files(genJaxb.classesDir).builtBy(genJaxb))

    jaxb "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.1.7"
}
```

From the logs the exact JAR causing this is `org.springframework/spring-core/5.1.8.RELEASE.jar`. Adding the `compileOptions` block is mentioned in other answers as a fix but it hasn't fixed this issue. How can I fix this?

Comment: To be clear I must use SDK 25 (Android N), not 26 like the error message says.

Comment: you can Go with these ref. Link. It might be helpful to you.
[Jar File Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633710/how-to-find-cause-of-error-when-dexing-methodhandle-invoke-and-methodhandle-inv)
[JAVA VErsion Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891730/invoke-customs-are-only-supported-starting-with-android-0-min-api-26)

Comment: I've seen those. That's why I added the compileOptions. And like I've said I can't use SDK 26. So they don't help unfortunately.

Comment: So I see you're using Spring Boot and not Spring for Android which is a bit of complicated scenario. IMHO, Spring Boot is only for Java Applications and not Android Applications as the means of bootstrapping is primarily made for pure Java Applications. However you could use Spring for Android and include the Spring WebServices library (`spring-ws-core`) and hence perform SOAP requests as such. But anything that has the term 'boot' in it is pretty much not going to work on Android.

Comment: I'm only using Spring Boot for the SOAP client. It doesn't look like Spring for Android has one though (unless I'm missing it). My only requirement is to create and parse SOAP requests on Android with code generation from the WSDL, so if Spring for Android can do that please let me know.

Comment: You requirement is to consume a SOAP Web Service on Android side. So Android will be the client, while spring boot is the server.

I don't know any tool about source code generation on Android. In any case in the paste I followed this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/

Comment: This library might be of use to you https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/430

Comment: @jbrown You should use some other library other than that

Answer (score 3):

Did you try ksoap?

https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android

Looks like it should do soap, is alive and works for android.

> The ksoap2-android project provides a lightweight and efficient SOAP
>   client library for the Android platform.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. No WSDL generation but probably better than manually constructing SOAP envelopes.

Comment: Hi @Maksim any idea How to configure ksoap2 in build.gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use a different library in order to make your SOAP calls.  This is what I've used which supports versions of the SDK as far back as 14.

```
private void GetSomeStuff(String myterm) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {


try {

     String strStuff2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"+
     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"+
     "<soap:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">"+
     "<wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>my username</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText\">my password</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soap:Header>"+
     "<soap:Body> <GetSomeStuff xmlns=\"https://mycompany.com.MyService\">"+
     "<term>" + myterm + "/term></GetSomeStuff></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";


    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://mycompany.com/MyService.svc");        
    StringEntity se;

    se = new StringEntity(strStuff2,HTTP.UTF_8);


    httppost.setHeader("SOAPAction", "https://mycompany.com.MyService/GetSomeStuff”);


    se.setContentType("text/xml");  
    httppost.setEntity(se);  


    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();      

    HttpResponse theresponse = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);

    StatusLine statusLine = theresponse.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = theresponse.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }

        String theXML = stringBuilder.toString();

        int start = theXML.indexOf("<GetSomeStuffResult>") + 21;
        int end = theXML.indexOf("</GetSomeStuffResult>") - 1;

        // We didn't get the response we expected
        if ((start < 0) || (end < 0) || (start==end)) {
            Log.i(“MyApp”,”Empty Response from GetSomeStuffResult");
            return;
        }

        String myData = theXML.substring(start, end);

        if (myData() > 0) {
            try {
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(myData);

                String deptDesc = jObject.getString("DepartmentDescription");
                String areaCode = jObject.getString("area_code");
                String phoneNumber = jObject.getString("phone_nbr");
                String title = jObject.getString("title");

                String fullPhoneNumber = "";

                if (phoneNumber.length() == 7) {
                    fullPhoneNumber = "(" + areaCode + ") " + phoneNumber.substring(0, 3) + "-" + phoneNumber.substring(3, 7);
                } else {
                     fullPhoneNumber = "(" + areaCode + ") " + phoneNumber;
                }

                SharedPreferences appPrefs =
                        getSharedPreferences("appPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);

                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appPrefs.edit();
                prefsEditor.putString("Title",title);
                prefsEditor.putString("DeptDescr",deptDesc);
                prefsEditor.putString("PhoneNumber",fullPhoneNumber);

                prefsEditor.commit();   

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    } else {
         Log.e(“MyApp”, "Failed to GetSomeStuff”);
    }


} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is what SOAP did to the world.

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework/spring-core/5.1.8.RELEASE.jar` won't work with `minSdkVersion 25` and it's not even and Android library, but a Java library. It strictly demands `minSdkVersion 26`:

```
MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact
are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
```

- [ksoap2-android](http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/getting-started.html) might indeed be more compatible (the most common) or
- [wsdl2ksoap2-android](https://code.google.com/archive/p/wsdl2ksoap2-android/) with on-device "automatic source code generating from WSDL".

... there are a few others linked; some require POJO generation on Desktop Java.

Comment: @jbrown the question was "how can I fix this?" - which I've not repeated at all.